# WebKit Inspector: Open Resource in TextMate

Tags: javascript, webkit, web-inspector

I thought it would be nice to open a resource from the web inspector sidebar in directly TextMate instead of the web inspector source view, but adding

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.onload = function() {
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
                if(links[i].className==="webkit-html-resource-link") {
                    links[i].addEventListener('click',function(e) {
                        console.log('openInTextmate', e);
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var tmLocation = 'txmt://open/?url=' + e.target.href;
                        window.location = tmLocation;
                    },false);
                }
            };
        };
    </script>
```

to the inspector.html didn't work. The event listeners are added but never fired. Does somebody have some experience of why this could be like this?

Comment: I'd love to get this working.  How did you add/edit inspector.html?

Comment: Take the source of Webkit https://www.webkit.org/building/checkout.html and build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that the click event propagation is stopped before the event reaches your handler. This happens in WebInspector.documentClick(inspector.js):

http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/WebCore/inspector/front-end/inspector.js&q=WebInspector.documentClick&exact_package=chromium&l=728

I believe you can put your code directly into WebInspector.documentClick to make it work for now. It also sounds like a good feature request for inspector extension API.

Comment: I've filed a bug against Web Inspector regarding this feature: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51526